# With XAMPP installed I've created a DB but now I re-installed it and it asks for a 'user@DB' that does not exist in the new XAMPP

Tags: php, mysql, apache, tomcat, xampp

I'm a new intern and I had XAMPP already installed on the computer that the company gave to me and it had there a DB there but I don't know why the XAMPP crashed and I've needed to re-install it and delete all the folders associated to it. For that reason all the DataBases that existed there were, normally, deleted.

Now when I installed XAMPP again and created "testlink" DB and "testlink" user I go to "localhost/MYAPP" I get the following message:

[image]

I guess it's looking for a user named 'testlinkuser' but as you can see here:

[image]

there's no user named 'testlinkuser'.

Maybe when I uninstalled the "first" XAMPP and deleted it's folders it had a DB named 'testlink' and a user named 'testlinkuser'?

But if so, why is he trying to reach the old user from the old DB and not the new user from the new DB?

Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe you have to set up new database username and password in your app config?

Comment: modify the mysql connection details in your code to match the new username and password

Answer (score 0):

Execute "setup_xampp.bat" file located in your xampp folder (the new installation). This should sort it . Also do provide details like was the new installation made to the same local drive (C:/D: etc.). Also were you able to do a clean uninstall.

Cheers!

Comment: I uninstalled it. The old XAMPP was on C:/xamp. And after the uninstall deleted the xamp folder and created a new one and create it in a new C:/xamp folder.

Comment: did you run the file I asked you to? If yes, does it work now?

Comment: Will try now! Thanks.

Comment: Did you make changes to the `myapp` database configuration file ? Can you post the folder structure of `myapp`

Comment: what you mean by "myapp database config file"? The application is an integration of a project written in java with a big one written in PHP.

Comment: The app "myapp" communicates with the database using settings it has saved in its configuration file. Why dont you start by searching for "testlinkuser" in the app folder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97412/discussion-between-tito-and-aman).

Answer (score 0):

Something I would do first:

What happens if you just try to make Those database and user?
And maybe you can copy the data from someone elses phpmyadmin?